# Is it possible to create a Stored Procedure for Select statements?

Tags: postgresql

If no, please suggest efficient alternatives if possible, I'll edit my question and include the source code if requested

Comment: Yes, you can, but what is the point?

Comment: If you want to return something use a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to encapsulate a SQL statement into something "callable", then put it into a function

```
create function get_data(p_some_value int)
  returns table (some_number int, some_date date, some_value text)
as
$$
  select c1, c2, c3
  from some_table
  where x1 = p_some_value;
$$
language sql
stable;
```

Answer (score -1):

A stored procedure is a prepared SQL code that you can save, so the code can be reused over and over again.

### Stored Procedure Syntax:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procedure_name
AS
sql_statement
GO;
```

- If you have an SQL query that you write over and over again, save it as a stored procedure, and then just call it to execute it.
- You can also pass parameters to a stored procedure so that the stored procedure can act based on the parameter value(s) that is passed.